# Command to add Parameters in regedit

Tags: windows, command-prompt, regedit

What is the command to add 
"TcpTimedWaitDelay" decimal=30  under "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\TCPIP\Parameters" ?

What is the command to delete it?